Compatibility relations between atlases (differential manifolds)
I'm starting to study Antoni A. Kosinski, Differential Manifolds and have stalled at the second page.
A chart over a topological space $M$ is defined as an open subset $U$ of $M$ with a homeomorphism $h: U \to$ an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$.
For some $r\in\mathbb N$, a $C^r$ atlas is a collection of charts such that for any two charts $(U,h)$ and $(U',h')$, the restriction of $h'\circ h^{-1}$ to $h(U \cap U')$ is $C^r$.
Lastly we have the definition of compatibility of atlases: two $C^r$ atlases are compatible if their union is an atlas.
The text then states that this compatibility is an equivalence relation. It is indeed trivially reflexive and symmetric, but is it transitive? This is not clear to me.
If we have three atlases $A$, $A'$ and $A''$ such that $A$ and $A'$ are compatible and $A'$ and $A''$ too, this means that for any three charts $(U,h)$, $(U',h')$ and $(U'',h'')$ respectively in each of these atlases, we have $h'\circ h^{-1}$ $C^r$ over $h(U \cap U')$ and $h''\circ h'^{-1}$ $C^r$ over $h'(U' \cap U'')$. This easily leads to $h''\circ h^{-1}$ being $C^r$ over $h(U \cap U' \cap U'')$. But what we need is for $h''\circ h^{-1}$ to be $C^r$ over the whole of $h(U \cap U'')$! I don't see how we can obtain this result.
This feels a bit like nitpicking, but since these are fundamental notions I'd like it to be clear.

You can do it like this : Fix a point in the double intersection, and show that there is a open set around that point (which will be your triple intersection) and your function is $C^r$ over it. It's done somewhere on this site I am sure.

To prove compatibility of $A$ and $A''$, you must prove that for any two charts $(U,h)$ and $(U'',h'')$ respectively in each of those two atlases, we have that $h'' \circ h^{-1}$ is $C^r$ over $h''(U \cap U'')$.
To prove this, pick $p \in U \cap U''$. Now you are free to pick any chart $(U',h')$ in the atlast for $A''$ and carry out the argument you wrote, based on knowing compatibility of the two charts $(U,h)$, $(U',h')$ and copmatibility of the two charts $(U',h')$ and $(U'',h'')$. Notice that the chart $(U',h')$ that you pick will depend on $p$, but that's okay, in fact that's a positive feature of the proof.

Thanks for your answer. It's a bit mixed up in the expression of the different sets (my point is the compatibility between $A$ and $A''$, not $A'$ and $A''$, for instance), but is still understandable and does answer my question, I think.

Ah yes, the first $A'$ should be an $A$, I think that fixes it.
